# How do you display big notfications with buttons?

Tags: java, android, statusbar

What I am trying to do is make the big notification with at least one button ( if i'm suppose to have at least 2, i'll accept that).

```
public void notification() {



   notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   notification.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(notification)
   .bigText("lololololololoolololooloololoolooolloll")
   .setBigContentTitle("Big Title")
   .setSummaryText("Big Summary"))
   //.setContentTitle("Title")
   //.setContentText("Summary")
   //.setTicker("Idk what this is really...")
   .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.holo_pressed_blue);


    //vibrates when notification comes up
    Notification note = notification.build();
   note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


   manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   manager.notify(0, notification.build());
```

Also if it's not to much trouble, with a small notification, how do you keep the notification in the status bar and it won't allow the user to remove it from the status bar, unless an action is made in the app?

Comment: A good thing would be to add `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` to your `Notification`'s flags.

Comment: Did you went through the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html ?

Comment: @shkschneider I did, problem is that it's not recognizing "CommonConstants" on my android studio IDE, and I looked it up, no solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the [official Tutoria](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html)l.

The `CommonConstants` you are struggling with are just user-defined constants:

See https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/samples/training/notify-user/src/com/example/android/pingme/CommonConstants.java?repo=platform--development&name=jb-dev&r=fc0d593056584555189bc7f4aa36ca32ac9386b4 or https://github.com/nRike/Android-simple-notification/blob/master/src/mx/androidtitlan/simplenotification/CommonConstants.java

Take your packageName and append ".EXTRA_MESSAGE" to it etc.